# Is there a preferred position for the tag "label for", using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i have a single-page web-app with ~2000 input elements, and i try now to make some performance tuning.
The question is: from the performance point of view, is in JQM a preferred order to write the tag pairs:

```
<input type="radio" name="e1-bin" id="e1-bin-0" value="1M" />
<label for="e1-bin-0">1 Module</label>
```

or maybe is better to write first the "label for" tag and then the "input" (or "select") tag?
I ask this, because JQM, like others javascript-frameworks, are doing some "heavy" manipulation of the DOM, to style the elements and render the user interface.

Is somewhere a benchmark for this, or is the order of the tags in the HTML simply not releveant for the performance?

Comment: What makes you think it's relevant?

Comment: Because of the DOM transformation, for example the "select" tag is transformed by jqm to an anchor tag and a series of span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that shouldn't have an impact on performance. You could do some profiling but the difference would be trivial if any. For eliminating the chance of your results being ruined by the network, you could do it locally and have a js script to generate 2000 elements this way or the other way and begin a counter right before jquery mobile kicks in. Checking the source code of [jquery mobile 1.3.2](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js) 
I couldn't fine any section of some relevance. These two options are very similar. It's not like there are any tags between them. I would suggest these two links for some performance tips, although irrelevant on what you asked, because I think you are looking at the wrong place :

1. [jquery official forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tips-for-speeding-up-jquery-mobile)
2. A [blog post](http://therockncoder.blogspot.gr/2012/06/three-quick-performance-tips-for.html) that has a pretty good tip about bubbling that came handy in a project I worked.

Comment: I agree with you, that shouldn't have an impact on performance. Thats was just to be sure, if someone has more background to check inside of the jqm source code.